# React native performance - App not loading content from server

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a react native application that loads server data and images , and
Im using fetch to load data from an API.

However, the app loads ONLY the first fetch call successfully, then fails to load all following calls to external server, including plain json fetch calls and images. Any call AFTER the first fetch will just timeout

**So in summary:**

- 1st fetch : Success
- 2nd, 3rd, ...etc: Fail
- Images after the 1st fetch: Fail

Note: the images and json files loads fine on browser

**Code sample:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchA();
    this.fetchB();
}

fetchA(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
  console.log(responseData);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});


fetchB(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
  console.log(responseData);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

fetchB function fails

**Environment:**

- React native 0.44
- iOS

I googled for long but without any luck to find out the source of the issue . Any help please?

Comment: Can you share some code snippet?

Comment: i edited the question and added a sample

Comment: It shouldn't happen, can you try repeating the `this.fetchA` again instead of `this.fetchB`. To make sure there no error in your this.fetchB code. Also, the timeout error is tough to debug without your fetch code and server setup.

Comment: already tried that. does not matter which one comes first

Comment: After long debuging, i think that the problem is that React native can call single remote content at once, and if a data loading call (remote image or json file or any data) stuck and taking long time, then all other calls will just wait for that to finish. does that make sense ?